Помогите сделать наоборот print (not(x)"это число ноль")
Print (not (x)"это число ноль")
Этот код проверяет если x равен 0 принт выведет это число ноль а как сделать проверку на 1 без if и внутри принта пытался так print (x1"это число 1") но выдаёт ошибку

Прямо вот этот первый код выведет только ошибку.

переведите вопрос на русский язык.

Видимо, вы не читали ответ на ваш прошлый вопрос, потому и не приняли его, и опять то почти же самое спрашиваете

Без if это можно сделать вот так:
x = 1
print((x == 1) * "Это число 1")

Или усовершенствовать:
target = 4
x = 4
print((x == target) * f"Это число {target}")


А я даже сначала и не понял, что за код автор вопроса написал, как это должно работать. Хорошо, что вы разобрались )
